# An inequality in positive real continuous function

Tags: inequality, functional-inequalities

I proposed my conjecture as follows:

Let $f(x)$ is a positive real continuous function that is convex on $[m, M]$, let $m \le x_i \le M$, for $i=1,2,...,n$ then show that
$$\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)+.....+f(x_n)}{n} \le \frac{f(M)+ f(m)}{2f\left(\frac{M+m}{2}\right)} f\left(\frac{x_1+x_2+....x_n}{n}\right)$$

Equality holds if only if $m=x_1=x_2=....=x_n=M$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Try with Jensen's inequality

Comment: I tried, but I can not give my proof. I checked by my computer

Comment: I think you are missing a factor of $1/n$ on the LHS

Comment: @kennytm Thank to You very much, I edited

Comment: Doesn't it also hold with equality if $f$ is linear? Or if half the $x_i$'s are $m$, the other half $M$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a second conjecture in the comment to my first answer, so I am answering that here.  The conjecture is:

#### Conjecture:

$$ \frac{f(x_1)+...+f(x_n)}{n} - f(\frac{x_1+...+x_n}{n}) \leq \frac{f(M)+f(m)}{2}- f(\frac{M+m}{2}) $$
whenever $f$ is continuous and convex over the interval $[m,M]$ and $m \leq x_i\leq M$ for all $i$.

#### Counter-example:

Consider $m=0,M=1$.  Consider $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined with 2 piecewise linear segments over the intervals $[0,3/4]$ and $[3/4,1]$ with: 
\begin{align}
f(0) &= 2\\
f(3/4) &= 1\\
f(1) &= 2
\end{align}
Specifically: 
$$ f(x) =  \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
-(4/3)x + 2 &\mbox{ if $x \in [0, 3/4]$} \\
4x-2  & \mbox{ if $x \in [3/4,1]$} 
\end{array}
\right. $$
Then: 
$$ \frac{f(M)+f(m)}{2} - f(\frac{M+m}{2})= \frac{f(1)+f(0)}{2} - f(1/2) = 2/3$$

Now let $x_1=0, x_2=x_3=x_4=1$.  So:
$$ \frac{f(x_1)+...+f(x_4)}{4} - f(\frac{x_1+...+x_4}{4}) = 2-f(3/4)=1$$

Comment: Dear @Michael , but I think, in your proof f(x) is not convex, f(x) is linear

Comment: @OaiThanhĐào : What do you mean?  $f$ has a "v" shape so is certainly not linear.  It is almost like the absolute value function $|x|$ but with different slopes on each edge.

Comment: Can you check with  $f(x)=x^2$ ?

Comment: I mean: The conjucture 2 must be true with f''>0 and f'>0 @Michael

Comment: You can modify my example to use differentiable and increasing convex functions if you like.  Try this:  Fix $m=0, M=1$, let $g(x)$ be the function defined by the line segment between points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$, and draw a picture of a smooth, convex, increasing function $f(x)$ that lies below $g(x)$, meets $g(x)$ at the endpoints $x=0$ and $x=1$, and has a largest gap between $g(x)$ that _does not occur at $x=1/2$_. If the largest gap occurs at some point $x^*  \in (0,1)$, $x^*\neq 1/2$, so that $g(x^*)-f(x^*) > g(1/2)-f(1/2)$, note you can always approximate $x^*$ by a rational number.

Comment: Thank to dear @Michael , please see here:  

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/245092/variant-karamata-inequality

Answer (score 4):

What if you fix $\epsilon>0$ and consider $f:[0,3]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = (x-1)^2 + \epsilon$?  So $m=0, M=3$.  Let $x_1=0, x_2=2$.  So:

\begin{align}
\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)}{2}  &= \frac{f(0)+f(2)}{2} = 1 + \epsilon\\
f(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}) &= f(1) = \epsilon \\
\frac{f(M)+f(m)}{2} &= \frac{f(3)+f(0)}{2} = (5/2)+\epsilon\\
f(\frac{M+m}{2}) &= f(1.5) = (1/4)+\epsilon
\end{align}

So for a counter-example to your conjecture, we just find an $\epsilon>0$ such that: 
$$ 1+\epsilon > \left(\frac{(5/2)+\epsilon}{(1/4)+\epsilon}\right)\epsilon $$
which is true for all sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Specifically, $0<\epsilon<1/5$.

Comment: Thank to You very much, the conjecture is wrong

Comment: @OaiThanhĐào: it may hold, however, if you assume something stronger on your $f$, namely that $f>0$ and $\log f$ is convex on $[m,M]$.

Comment: @Michael , I am sorry, it may hold if we edit again:

$$\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)+.....+f(x_n)}{n}-f(\frac{x_1+x_2+....x_n}{n}) \le \frac{f(M)+ f(m)}{2}-f(\frac{M+m}{2})$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank to You very much

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio could you try your condition ?

Comment: @OaiThanhĐào : See counter-example in my second answer for your new conjecture.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  Yes, I Think with ln(f(x) Is convex on I the inequality is holds